# Do shiny apps data-scoping rules apply to ShinyProxy?

Tags: r, shiny, scope, shinyproxy

as far as I understand, ShinyProxy launches a separate container for every connected user, is it possible to share data among user sessions by using [these documented shiny scoping rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) (see *Objects visible across all sessions*)?

My use case involves loading a *big* static dataset in memory that is the same for every app user, so the correct approach here is to have a single copy of the dataset in memory and share it among all user sessions (= load it before the 'server' function). Does this work with ShinyProxy as explained in the above Shiny documentation?

Thanks in advance,

Juanje.